# Downhill Simplex Method

Tags: computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Is it possible to use Downhill Simplex Method for template matching?Let's say I have 40 landmarks on the edges of an object and I have pixel intesities of normal vectors on these landmarks and I want to use  Downhill Simplex Method for strecthing the template I have with iterations after each iteration i will check mean square of errors of the pixels I have in the template object and image I am working on?Anyone got an idea?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes. But Mean Square Error doesn't give you the best solution, I recommend using the Mahalanobis distance instead. Further details are to be found on the following reference: F. Arambula Cosio, J. Marquez Flores, and M. Padilla Castañeda. Use of simplex search in active shape models for improved boundary segmentation. Pattern Recognition Letters, 31:806—817, 2010.